# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: fileStream

Tags: asp.net, iis, crystal-reports-2008

i transferred application from old server to new one , trying to print from screen report to Crystal report as before this message appear "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: fileStream "
in old server its working normal but not in the new server .

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in crystal report must run the report with the new server ip  and new credential